# How do you use connect-roles with passportjs in Meanjs default generated code?

Tags: authentication, authorization, passport.js, roles, meanjs

I am just starting learning meanjs and want to use a role-based authorization method.connect-roles seems to be well fit, but I'm having trouble on how to use it with the provided passportjs authentication method.

I have looked around and found no documentation on this. Can anyone help explain?